# Where does the sign come from in the twist homomorphism of the Alexander Whitney map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

$\require{AMScd}$

Consider the Alexander Whitney map: $AW: S_*(X\times Y)\to S_*(X)\otimes S_*(Y)$ given by $AW(\sigma)=\Sigma_{p+q=n}(p_X\circ\sigma\circ\alpha_p)\otimes(p_Y\circ\sigma\circ\beta_q)$ with $p_X: X\times Y\to X$, $p_Y: X\times Y\to Y$, $\sigma: \Delta^n\to X\times Y$, $\alpha_p: \Delta^p\to\Delta^n$ and $\beta_q: \Delta^q\to\Delta^n$. I want to know where the element $(-1)^{pq}$ comes from in the twist homomorphism (or whatever it's called): $\tau: S_*(X)\otimes S_*(Y)\to S_*(Y)\otimes S_*(X)$ allegedly given by $\tau(x\otimes y)=(-1)^{pq}y\otimes x$. I don't see why the diagram below cannot commute without it...

$\begin{CD}
S_*(X\times Y) @>t_*>> S_*(Y\times X)\\
@VAW_{X,Y}VV @VAW_{Y,X}VV\\
S_*(X)\otimes S_*(Y) @>\tau>> S_n(Y)\otimes S_n(X)\\
\end{CD}$

Comment: Could you include where you got this square from?

Comment: @ConnorMalin I was looking at different notes on the AW map, you have one here on [page 7](http://ckottke.ncf.edu/docs/acyclic.pdf) for instance. Though notice the two diagrams are wrong in that _both_ $T_{\#}$ and $\tau$ should switch elements, ie $T_{\#}$ maps incorrectly in both squares (but the definitions right above the diagrams are correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between a commutative diagram and a chain homotopy commutative diagram. In the notes you link, they do not claim the diagrams are commutative, only up to chain homotopy. It is very obvious that it can't be commutative on the nose: a map of spaces sends the basis elements of the singular chains to other basis elements of singular chains. Notably, the image of a basis element cannot have a negative sign. As well, the Alexander-Whitney map does not introduce negative signs, but the twisting map $\tau$ can. Hence, the square can't be commutative.

However, on homology negative signs can be introduced. For example, if you map $S^1 \times S^1$ to itself by your coordinate swap map $t$, then the fundamental class $[S^1 \times S^1]$ is negated. This is because the fundamental class is determined by the local orientation it induces, and the swap map reverses local orientation.

More generally, if we apply a permutation $\rho$ to the vertices of all the simplices making up a cycle $\sigma$, the result is $-1^{sgn(\rho)}\sigma$ plus some boundary. Now let's take the homotopy commutative square and apply homology. Then it becomes actually commutative, and the sign $-1^{pq}$ appears because we end up swapping the first p vertices with the last q vertices and this has sign $pq$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference. But regarding the statement (in the notes) that diagram (9) "is not commutative in general", is there an actual computation or example that shows that ?

Comment: @sdm Like I said, the top composition will never take a standard basis element to something which has negatives in its standard basis expression, but the bottom composition can when $pq$ is odd.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for the answer !